# How to save a specific sheet of Google Spreadsheet a CSV values in a single cell of another sheet within the same Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can scripts be used to export the contents of one sheet as comma separated values, and save those comma separated values as text within a cell of a different sheet within the same spreadsheet?

Conversely, can scripts be used to read the contents of the comma separated values saved within a single cell on one sheet and load/view them formatted on another sheet?

Context: I have a sheet (Sheet A) with various transactions separated by row. I'd like to use a second sheet (Sheet B) as a template to journal qualitative questions about these transactions. At a click of a button or menu item, I'd like to save the contents of that 'journal entry' to a single cell within Sheet A. Additionally, I'd like a Sheet B, or a third sheet (C) to be able to select any given row of Sheet A and load the journal entry in a proper formatted way. It'd be great if editing and viewing could be done on the same sheet (B) but not absolutely necessary

### EDIT

Here is an [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MyT9WlPyM_iwSl3h3aUYWVDDPNKbHyBZfxXSB_UVkuo/edit?usp=sharing) of the data I'm working with. A solution with full code has been posted below.

You can see in the 'Journal' sheet, buttons are created to:

(1) Load Journal Template - This resets the information below Row 11, according to the 'Template' Sheet

(2) Load Journal entries - This loads the comma separated values (csv) from a single cell of the selected trade

(3) Save Journal entries - This saves the values within a subset of the below Journal area as a single cell of the trade selected by 'Select Trade'

Would love to hear your thoughts!

Comment: It would be useful to give you an accurate solution if you could show an example of your data and the result you want to obtain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I managed to put together. Below is the code for each of these processes described beneath 'Edit' in the original question:

(0) General Declarations

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('###');
let log = ss.getSheetByName("Log");
let journal = ss.getSheetByName("Journal");
let logData = log.getDataRange().getValues();
let ticker = journal.getRange("A7").getValue();
let pnL = journal.getRange("H7").getValue();
let num = journal.getRange("B7").getValue();
let templates = ss.getSheetByName("Templates");
```

(1) Load Journal Template:

```
function loadTemplates() {
  // Clear current journal content and formatting
  journal.getRange("12:100").clearContent();
  journal.getRange("12:100").clearFormat();
  journal.getRange("12:100").setDataValidation(null);

  // Load Templates
  // ABCD
  if(journal.getRange("A3").getValue() == "ABCD"){
    templates.getRange("2:61").copyTo(journal.getRange("12:71"));
  // OTHER
  } else if (ss.getSheetByName("Journal").getRange("A3").getValue() == "ORB"){
    templates.getRange("63:122").copyTo(journal.getRange("12:71"));
  };
};
```

(2) Load Journal

```
function loadJournal() {
  for(let i = 0; i < logData.length; i++){
    if(logData[i][5].toString().includes(ticker) && logData[i][22] === num){
      journal.getRange("D13:G80").setValues(Utilities.parseCsv(logData[i][23]));
    };
  };
};
```

(3) Save Journal

```
function saveJournal() {
  // Declaring the range that will make up the Array
  let journalData = journal.getRange("D13:G80").getValues();
  let output = [];
  journalData.forEach(function(dataArray) {
      let data = dataArray.join(",");
      output += data + "\r\n";
  });
  // Finding correct trade to edit  
  for(let i = 0; i < logData.length; i++){
    if(logData[i][5].toString().includes(ticker) && logData[i][22] === num){
      log.getRange(i+1,24).setValue(output);
      //Resize workaround using Google Sheets API bc setWrap and setRowHeight do not work 
      const requests = {updateDimensionProperties: {
        properties: {pixelSize: 21},
        range: {sheetId: log.getSheetId(), startIndex: i+1, endIndex: i+1, dimension: "ROWS"},
        fields: "pixelSize"
      }};
      Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: requests}, ss.getId());
    };  
  };
};
```

Would love to hear your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need scripts for this action if this is small contents.
When you speak about exporting sheet contents to a single cell I suppose you can use textjoin formula to put a table in a cell and separate it by comma.

`=textjoin(",";false;B1:C7)` - puts contents of B1:C7 in your cell.

To unfold it, you can use SPLIT formula

```
=split(B11;",")
```

makes a row of values from a content of B11

```
 = transpose(split(B11;","))
```

Makes it a coulmn.

If ranges are bigger you can still fold and unfold them without using a single script. But first I would habe to see some data structure.